# git config proxy for a project with submodules

Tags: git, proxy, configuration, settings, git-submodules

I have the following project setup

```
ProjectA  
    -- [sub moduleB]
       -- file1
       -- file2 etc
    -- [sub moduleC]
  --file1
  --file2
  --etc
```

`ProjectA` is its own project.  As are the submodules.  Each have their own files and folders and git repository.  However the problem I have is that due to company restrictions the stuff in the submodules requires me to connect to it via a proxy.  e.g. ProjectA is hosted internally but the submodules are not.  Think of the submodules as like external plugins for a bigger app.

I currently get around this by manually setting the proxy.

So inside projectA I clear the proxy setting by typing

```
git config --global http.proxy ""
```

When im in the submodule I then set the proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<proxy url>:8080
```

Can I configure git to remember the proxy on a folder level?  So I don't have to keep remembering (and sometimes forgetting) to run this config command.  I would like to just do it once and then forget about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer -  I do not have an environment similar to yours where I can test this

When you configure something like

```
git config --global
```

The `--global` says "put this configuration value in the `.gitconfig` file in my home directory".  Git applies your home version of `.gitconfig` to *all* repositories you access.  If you were to instead configure like

```
git config http.proxy http://your.proxy:8080
```

It would place the configuration entry in the current repository config file, which is located in $REPO/.git/config.  So in your instance having http.proxy set in each submodule, but having http.proxy have no value in the superproject or in your home config might do the trick.

So unset it globally

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Then navigate to each submodule and do

```
git config http.proxy http://your.proxy:8080
```